# Hide items with a certain tag in agenda based on time of day

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Is it possible to hide items with a certain tag after at specific time of the day?  For example, I'd like that after 5pm and on weekends, :WORK: items don't appear in the agenda.

EDIT: I am dealing with scheduled items and relying on org-agenda-list function.

Comment: Yes, but it will be a little slow if you have lots of deadlines and/or scheduled.  Please edit your post (or add a comment) to specify whether you are dealing with deadlines or scheduled, and if both, which one you want to evaluate.  In my mind, I am thinking of a custom `org-agenda-skip-function`.  Also, please specify which of the the three (3) main functions you are relying upon -- `org-agenda-list`, `org-search-view`, or `org-tags-view`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize skipping specific entries in `org-agenda` by using a [skip function](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-agenda-views.html).  This is a function (or lisp form) that will be evaluated at each headline and should return `nil` (to not skip the headline) or the point of the next headline to consider (which is typically the next headline, but could be, for example the next sibling to speed the search up).

In this case, we just need a function to skip the headline if it has a certain tag (get those with `org-get-tags-at`) and the `(current-time)` is after a certain hour:

```
(defun skip-tag-after (tag hour)
  (let* ((next-headline (save-excursion
                          (or (outline-next-heading) (point-max))))
        (current-headline (or (and (org-at-heading-p)
                                   (point))
                              (save-excursion (org-back-to-heading))))
        ;; (now (decode-time (current-time)))
        (target (decode-time (current-time)))
        (day (nth 6 target))
        )
    (setcar (last target 7) hour)
    (setcar (last target 8) 0)
    (if (and (member tag (org-get-tags-at current-headline))
             (or (eq day 0)
                 (eq day 6)
                 (time-less-p (apply #'encode-time target) (current-time))))
            next-headline
            nil)))
```

This doesn't consider the weekday, but that logic

You can either `(setq (setq org-agenda-skip-function-global '(skip-tag-after "WORK" 17))` to skip such headlines globally in every agenda, or set it set `org-agenda-skip-function` locally inside a `org-agenda-custom-command` to affect just that agenda.

Comment: What if I have several such tags: one is for working-time, another is for evenings 7 days a week, etc? How do I combine filtering on all of them?

Comment: You can use a lisp form as the value of `org-agenda-skip-function` by for example setting it to `(or (skip-tags-after "WORK" 17) (skip-tags-after "HOME" 9))`

Answer (score 3):

A very simple workaround would would be to make a special agenda view (or views) that you only use on evenings and weekends.

To give a very simple example, you could customize `org-agenda-custom-commands` by adding something like `("x" "No Work" tags-todo "-work" nil)`. Then on evenings and weekends you can pull up your overall agenda view with <kbd>C-c a x</kbd>.

Comment: This is my current setup and it works but I was considering an alternative.

Comment: `org-agenda-custom-commands` also allows you to set custom functions... It should definitely be possible to do what you want that way (a simple `if`) , but I don't know elisp well enough to show you how exactly.